# RewriteRule for multiple predefined subdomains to website root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a list of predefined subdomains to my websites root.

I am struggling with the wildcards, can anyone help?

```
# Redirect all old subdomains
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(random|sub|domains)\.example\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L, R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It needs to be predefined and done via .htaccess as it's Google that is picking up and hitting 404's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this in your .htaccess then your RewriteRule will never match if you have a leading slash. Remove it and it should work i.e

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Currently throws an internal server error as soon as I add my above rule - not sure why.

Comment: sorry - I cut and paste your code and missed the space after the L. Fixed above